# Remote Access to Secured Jenkins Server

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a Jenkins installation on a machine running Windows Server 2008.  The Jenkins installation is secured using Jenkins own user database with matrix-based security authorization.  Anonymous users don't have any access, except to register an account.  I have set up an account and gave this account full access.

Now I'd like to trigger a build remotely from a different machine that hosts the repository.  I believe this should be possible by accessing the following URL:

```
https://[username]:[user_api_token]@[address.of.jenkins]:8080/job/[project]/build?token=[project_api_token]
```

However, this does not seem to be working for me.  When I access this site in a browser, Jenkins forwards to the login-page, and does not start the build.

What am I doing wrong?  It seems to be an authentication problem, as I'm not logged in after opening the URL above.  Furthermore, if I give anonymous users full access, the URL works.

Comment: You haven't specified which version of Jenkins. The doco describes issues with versions of wget (if that is what your using). https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Jenkins 1.490.  I'm using a regular web browser (Chrome to be specific) to access the URL.  I believe this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the build from a command-line program like curl:

```
curl http://[userid]:[user_token]@localhost:8080/job/[project]/build?token=[proj_token]
```

or

```
curl --user [userid]:[user_token] http://localhost:8080/job/[project]/build?token=[proj_token]
```

I think your issue could be browser related, embedding credentials within the URL (Firefox pops up a warning in my case telling me I'm about to login to Jenkins)